# How to append values from one array to another array at same keys?

Tags: php

I have following two arrays

First

```
Array
(
    [45712] => En Vogue Queen Upholstered Bed == 1675
    [45713] => En Vogue  Nightstand == 1315
    [45714] => En Vogue  Drawer Dresser == 1719
    [45715] => En Vogue  Mirror == 1225
    [45716] => En Vogue  Floor Mirror  == 1349
)
```

Second

```
Array
(
    [45712] => SLF-8480-252-256-508 == 23775
    [45713] => SLF-8480-050 == 17221
    [45714] => SLF-8480-010 == 17217
    [45715] => SLF-8480-030 == 17218
    [45716] => SLF-8480-037 == 17219
)
```

I want output like

```
Array
(
    [45712] => SLF-8480-252-256-508 == 23775 En Vogue Queen Upholstered Bed == 1675
    [45713] => SLF-8480-050 == 17221 == En Vogue  Nightstand == 1315
    [45714] => SLF-8480-010 == 17217 == En Vogue  Drawer Dresser == 1719
    [45715] => SLF-8480-030 == 17218 == Mirror == 1225
    [45716] => SLF-8480-037 == 17219 == Floor Mirror  == 1349
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `foreach` and `isset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1 = array(45712 => "En Vogue Queen Upholstered Bed == 1675", 45713 => "En Vogue  Nightstand == 1315", 45714 => "En Vogue  Drawer Dresser == 1719", 45715 => "En Vogue  Mirror == 1225", 45716 => "En Vogue  Floor Mirror  == 1349");
$array2 = array(45712 => "SLF-8480-252-256-508 == 23775", 45713 => "SLF-8480-050 == 17221", 45714 => "SLF-8480-010 == 17217", 45715 => "SLF-8480-030 == 17218", 45716 => "SLF-8480-037 == 17219");

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value){
    $array2[$key] = $value." == ".$array1[$key];
}

print_r($array2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [45712] => SLF-8480-252-256-508 == 23775 == En Vogue Queen Upholstered Bed == 1675
    [45713] => SLF-8480-050 == 17221 == En Vogue  Nightstand == 1315
    [45714] => SLF-8480-010 == 17217 == En Vogue  Drawer Dresser == 1719
    [45715] => SLF-8480-030 == 17218 == En Vogue  Mirror == 1225
    [45716] => SLF-8480-037 == 17219 == En Vogue  Floor Mirror  == 1349
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    45712 => "En Vogue Queen Upholstered Bed == 1675",
    45713 => "En Vogue  Nightstand == 1315",
    45714 => "En Vogue  Drawer Dresser == 1719",
    45715 => "En Vogue  Mirror == 1225",
    45716 => "En Vogue  Floor Mirror  == 1349"
);
$array2 = array(
    45712 => "SLF-8480-252-256-508 == 23775",
    45713 => "SLF-8480-050 == 17221",
    45714 => "SLF-8480-010 == 17217",
    45715 => "SLF-8480-030 == 17218",
    45716 => "SLF-8480-037 == 17219"
);

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($array1[$key] == $array1[$key]) {
        $array3[] = $array1[$key] . " == " . $array2[$key];
    }
}
print_r($array3);
?>
```

Output: http://codepad.org/91f3NFEr

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work.

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($yoursecondarr as $k=$v)
{
$new_arr[$k]=$v." ".$yourfirstarr[$k];
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
  if (isset($second_array[$key]) {
    $second_array[$key] = ' ' . $value; 
  } else {
    $second_array[$key] = $value;
  }
}
print_r($second_array);
```